# Show form in each block was created by ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md" ng-repeat="song in songs">
        <div class="title"><div class="add">+</div></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click over `<div class="add">+</div>` I need to show form here:

```
<div class="row">
        // Show form here with submit button
        <div class="col-md" ng-repeat="song in songs">...
```

When I submit form I need to add new item `<div class="item"></div>` in this columns where was opened form.

How to do this in AngularJS?
Can I insert form dinamicly or I must set form at once in `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Is there a reason why this question is tagged with ``angular2``?

Comment: Sorry, AngularJS 1.5

Comment: Seems I know. I should to pass to ng-click="add(item)" of current collection in column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
    $scope.formView = false;
    $scope.itemView = false;
    $scope.plusShow = true;
  
  $scope.songs =['sample']
  
  $scope.showFrom = function(){
    $scope.formView = true;
    $scope.plusShow = false;
  };
  
  $scope.submit = function(){ 
   $scope.formView = false;
    $scope.itemView = true;    
    $scope.plusShow = false;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <form  ng-if="formView">
      <!-- from content -->
      <input ng-click="submit()" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
  
  
    <div class="item" ng-if="itemView">items</div>
   

    <div class="col-md" ng-repeat="song in songs">
        <div class="title">
          <div class="add"  ng-click="showFrom()" ng-if="plusShow">+</div>
        </div>      
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: How does code detect that hide/open block in block where was click?

Comment: It does not work where there are some items in ng-repeat

Comment: @Halama please create a plnkr